# ModelForm confusion

Tags: django, templates, django-forms

This:

```
class ArticleForm(Form):  
       title = forms.CharField(label="Title", max_length=255,required=True)
short = forms.CharField(label="Short Description",widget=Textarea(attrs={'rows':'4'}),required=True)
       content = forms.CharField(label="Content",widget=Textarea(attrs={'rows':'20'}),required=True)
      categories = forms.MultipleChoiceField(label="Audit Group",choices=[(o.id, o.real_name()) for o in AuditGroup.objects.all()], widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple
```

)

was being nicely rendered as a view - then I realized I needed a `ModelForm`! ;)

But this:

```
class ArticleForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
         model = Article
         fields = ("title","categories","topic","short_desc","content")
         widgets = {
             'short_desc':Textarea(attrs={"rows":'4'}) ,
             'content':Textarea(attrs={"rows":'20'}) ,
             'categories':CheckboxSelectMultiple(choices=[(o.id, o.real_name()) for o in AuditGroup.objects.all()]),
             'topic':CheckboxSelectMultiple(choices=[(o.id, o.name) for o in Topic.objects.all()])
         }
```

is not correctly showing the labels in my view. This should be accomplished by the `o.real_name()` and the `o.name` functions.

Any idea? Thanks!

Comment: Can you post the model definition? And the labels being rendered?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either you can set `verbose_name` on your model as suggested by Paulo.

Or if you do not want to touch your model you can explicitly define your field on the form.

```
class ArticleForm(ModelForm):

    short_desc = forms.CharField(label="Short Description")
    #similarly any change you want in other fields.
    class Meta:
        model = Article
        fields = ("title","categories","topic","short_desc","content")
```

Another way:
If you do not want to redefine the form fields and only want to change the label, you can do it in `__init__`

```
class ArticleForm(ModelForm):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(ArticleForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['short_desc'].label = "Short description"
    class Meta:
        model = Article
        fields = ("title","categories","topic","short_desc","content")
```

Answer (score 2):

Set the `verbose_name` parameter in each of your `Model`'s fields as you would like to be rendered in the labels. For example:

```
class Article(Model):  
   title = forms.CharField(verbose_name="Title", ...)
   short = forms.CharField(verbose_name="Short Description", ...)
   content = forms.CharField(verbose_name="Content", ...)

   ...
```